# Cookie is equivalent to variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, frontend

I am wondering how it would be possible to create a cookie in JavaScript and set the value of the cookie to a variable called s. I would like the cookie to update. For example, if the variable s has a value of 5, the cookie will become 5 but if an event occurs and the variable changes to 6, the cookie with change to 6 as well. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,daysToExpire)
{
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(daysToExpire*24*60*60*1000));
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createCookie('s', 5, 30);">Set Cookie to 5</button>
<button onclick="createCookie('s', 6, 30);">Set Cookie to 6</button>
<button onclick="createCookie('s', 7, 30);">Set Cookie to 7</button>
```